# Multi line time series pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, multiline, linegraph

I am trying to plot a multi line graph from pandas in python. I need three lines (positive, negative, neutral) and their number of occurrences during time. On the x-axis I would have the time, on the y- axis I would have the number of occurrences and I would have three lines in one graph. If there is no occurrence then it would be automatically zero (for example in th etable there is no occurrence for "negative" so in the graph the point would be zero). I am attaching the table that I would need to turn into graph.

```
d = datapandas.groupby(["date","classification"]).size()
```

[image]

The most left column is the number of occurrence of the classification during the date. I could not find any easy way to plot this kind of graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just to `unstack` the `classification` index and plot the graph:

```
d.unstack('classification').fillna(0).plot()
```

Note: you can avoid `groupby` by using `value_counts`:

```
d = datapandas.value_counts(['date', 'classification'])
```

Comment: just added fillna(0) before .plot and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `pivot` to rearrange your data and then call `plot()` this is by default `kind='line'`. To fill the missing values you can call `fillna(0)`.

If you have a MultiIndex call `reset_index('classification')` first.

```
df.pivot(columns='classification', values='value').fillna(0).plot()
```

Here is a complete minimal example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
t = '''date classification value
2021-12-24 neutral 3
2021-12-24 positiv 2
2021-12-25 neutral 1
2021-12-25 positiv 3
2021-12-26 neutral 1
2021-12-26 negative 2
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep='\s', parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
df.pivot(columns='classification', values='value').fillna(0).plot(kind='line')
```

[image: example with three lines]